# How can I change the language for all default files, folders, titles, etc.? Or how can I recreate them?

Tags: sharepoint-online, language, default

I bought Office 365 Business with SharePoint in Thailand because I live in Thailand and they have a special price here. On my first login the user interface and all files, folder, titles, etc. were in Thai.

But I want to use English and not Thai.

I was able to change the language from the user interface. But there are still lots of files and folders in Thai.

Is there somewhere a "button" to change all default data to English?

I guess if I would have subscribed i.e. in the USA then I would have the same file structure but in English. This is what I want.

Until now I did not add any data. So if everything is deleted and created from scratch again that is fine with me.

**How can I make my SharePoint as if I would have signed up in English?**

This is a sample of what I see:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not any button for changing default language.
If you want to have SharePoint default in English, you should create the whole Office 365 tenant in english, cause you can **create Sites in English** but you cannot edit the Root Site https://company.sharepoint.com otherwise you can **create Microsoft Ticket** and ask them if they can change the default localization to English for whole tenant...

- You can change preferable language for users, [link here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28994535/How-to-change-the-default-language-of-an-Office-365-tenant.html)
- Or user can change it for its own. [link here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-your-personal-language-and-region-settings-caa1fccc-bcdb-42f3-9e5b-45957647ffd7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)
- [Here is some script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Change-the-default-003d42c6) for editing default language for all users, not tested

If its new tenant, maybe try delete them and create new one.

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: Thanks, I just contacted MS and asked them to change it. Let's see how this works. I will report back.

Comment: I contacted Microsoft Support 3 days ago and this is still not sorted. Until now, after lots of irrelevant information, they gave me the following links to delete and recreate the site. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/delete-site-collection https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/create-site-collection This works. But unfortunately the recreated site is still in Thai even if I select English as the site language. It seems the template is in Thai so any new created site will be in Thai. Waiting for MS for more info...

Comment: You have any custom template? Cause when you are creating site you are can select Default Language, you need to select English here instead of Thai (your default probably)

Comment: I selected English language and it still comes up in Thai. I repeated it several times and made a screenshot to be sure. I guess I have to wait for MS a little longer...

Comment: ok so this is now on Microsoft, just wait, hope they will solve this for You

Comment: Update: Now you have option in Central Administration, that you can replace root site with another prepared site. You can do it with PowerShell Command or in GUI
Invoke-SPOSiteSwap
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/modern-root-site